# Lotus Notes Developer Client had a great interactive guide to the Notes/Domino object model in R7.. where is the equivalent for R8 and 9?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

R7 had this reference resource as the home/welcome page for the Designer client. It was very useful for LotusScript programming. Where is there an equivalent for R8.x.x (or even R9)? Or is it possible to reconfigure the 8.5.3 Developer client to produce something similar?

There was a similar internet-based resource for R5, and I think I had a free wallchart at one stage. I am only an occasional LS programmer and haven't committed the object model, properties, methods and syntax to memory unfortunately, so I miss it.

[image: Lotus Notes R7 resource]

Comment: I'ts gone... You'll have to navigate through the NotesHelp

Comment: I think you could rip it from R7 Help and put it into R8 Help. R9 Help is useless - it does not contain most of LS object and designer goes to "html style" help - so you need to open help NSF (preferably R8 version) from client.

Answer (score 0):

Domino designer 8+ has no and cannot be configured to show the chart. I have the contrary impression on the chart as you. I think it's too dense and of little use(though I'm a professional notes developer). Actually it's easy to divide the two categories. All the UI classes are named with UI such as NotesUIDocument except rarely used form, button and navigator. A typical traverse of backend objects is NotesSession -> DB -> View -> Document.